# Tensorflow model with user-specific data

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

What's the best way to construct the data for and train a model with user-specific data? Should each user get their own model to ensure it learns specifics of their data? Or is it possible to create a global model that keeps users' data mostly separate (e.g. with a feature that identifies the user)?

The prediction task I have in mind is either regression or classification.

Answer (score 1):

There should be both the models.  The first model, a global one, will be trained to predict the general behavior.  Once it is done, it will be copied to every user and further tuned based on the user's individual behavior.